# CentOS: What to do with packages installed from DVD after network is enabled

Tags: centos, yum

I had to install a couple packages manually from the CentOS DVD before I had networking set up. Of course, yum reports them as "From repo : c7-media"

I want to know if, when any updates come out for these packages via online repos, I will get those, or if the original installation source will prevent me from seeing/retrieving them?

If it matters, I installed the packages by temporarily enabling the c7-media repo, and it is not enabled in its config file.

Now that I have network connectivity, should I remove those packages and re-add them from CentOS-Base to ensure I get all future updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special.

When an update is released for a package installed from DVD, you'll receive it over the network just like any other update.